# How deep can a variable passthrough to jinja go with a join?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Working on a project -flask/sqlalchemy/jinja. If I were to call a join, loop through the set acquire the data through a variable could I call upon that variable multiple layers deep? Example:

```
orders = Orders.query.join(Products, Orders.id==Products.order_id).all()
```

Loop through records and find the values:

```
 data = []
 for order in orders:
    object= {
        'id': order.id,
        'products': []
    }
    for product in order.products:
        product = {
            'name': product.name,
            'header':product.header
        }
        object['products'].append(product)
    data.append(object)
```

Render template passing data as data.

```
return render_template('something.jinja2', data=data)
```

In jinja can I do this?:

```
{% for d in data %}
   {{order.products.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

If I were to do more joins and more loops could I go deeper into relationships?

Answer (score 0):

loop in a loop in jinja

```
{% for d in data%}
{{ order.id}}
   {% for product in d.products %}
      {{product.name}}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```